Why is my PHP code not correctly updating my CRUD application?
I am trying to make a CRUD app for my business, I have little knowledge with PHP. I followed a guide that has proven to be successful until I got to the update portion.
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database= "replog_test";

//create connection
$connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

$id = "";
$service_dept="";
$po="";
$customer="";
$pcs="";
$equipment="";
$date_rec="";
$problem="";
$warr="";
$date_ship="";

$errorMessage = "";
$successMessage = "";

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
    //GET method: Show the data of the client

    if (!isset($_GET["id"])) {
        header("location: /novasvm/index.php");
        exit;
    }

    $id = $_GET["id"];

    // read the row of the selected client from the database table
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM replog WHERE id=$id";
    $result = $connection->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    if (!$row) {
        header("location: /novasvm/index.php");
        exit;
    }

    $service_dept = $row["service_dept"];
    $po = $row["po"];
    $customer = $row["customer"];
    $pcs = $row["pcs"];
    $equipment = $row["equipment"];
    $date_rec = $row["date_rec"];
    $problem = $row["problem"];
    $warr = $row["warr"];
    $date_ship = $row["date_ship"];
}
else {
    // POST method: Update the data of the client
    $service_dept = $_POST["service_dept"];
    $po = $_POST["po"];
    $customer = $_POST["customer"];
    $pcs = $_POST["pcs"];
    $equipment = $_POST["equipment"];
    $date_rec = $_POST["date_rec"];
    $problem = $_POST["problem"];
    $warr = $_POST["warr"];
    $date_ship = $_POST["date_ship"];

    do {
        if ( empty($service_dept) || empty($po) || empty($customer) || empty($pcs) || empty($equipment) || empty($date_rec) || empty($problem) || empty($warr)) {
            $errorMessage = "All fields except DATE SHIPPED are required";
            break;
        }

        $sql = "UPDATE replog " . 
                "SET service_dept = '$service_dept', po = '$po', customer = '$customer', pcs = '$pcs', equipment = '$equipment', date_rec = '$date_rec', problem = '$problem', warr = '$warr', date_ship = '$date_ship' " . 
                "WHERE id = '$id'";

        $result = $connection->query($sql);
        
        if (!$result) {
            $errorMessage = "Invalid Query: " . $connection->error;
            break;
        }

        $successMessage = "Client Updated Correctly";
        header("location: /novasvm/general/replog.php");
        exit;

    } while(false);
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../reset.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Repair Log</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h2>New Data</h2>

        <?php  
        if ( !empty($errorMessage)) {
            echo "
            <div>
                <strong>$errorMessage</strong>
            </div>
            ";
        }          
        ?>

        <form method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
            <div>
                <label>Service Department</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="service_dept" value="<?php echo $service_dept; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>PO Number</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="po" value="<?php echo $po; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Customer</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="customer" value="<?php echo $customer; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Pieces</label>
                <div>
                    <select name="pcs" id="">
                        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Equipment</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="equipment" value="<?php echo $equipment; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Date Received</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="date" name="date_rec" value="<?php echo $date_rec; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Problem / Serial No.</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="problem" value="<?php echo $problem; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Warranty</label>
                <div>
                    <select name="warr" id="">
                        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                        <option value="no">No</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Date Shipped</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="date" name="date_ship" value="<?php echo $date_ship; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php
            if (!empty($successMessage)) {
                echo "
                <div>
                    <strong>$successMessage</strong>
                </div>
                ";
            }
            ?>

            <div>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="/novasvm/general/replog.php" role="button">Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Once I submit the data it never actually updates on the xampp server nor the webpage. It stays exactly the same.
Expected update of database information not correctly functioning.

It should be executed once, as it checks the condition after the first run, isn't it?

Do any of the error messages trigger? Do you have full error reporting and logging turned on on the server? While debugging I strongly encourage avoiding all redirects, they can hide error messages. If something fails, die($errorMessage);. If something succeeds, die('success');. Once that's solve you can remove the die and add the redirects back in.

You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of prepared statements and bind_param. This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.

Thank you @ChrisHaas that is a very helpful insight. I will use this going forward.

I understand @aybnner, I will be fixing things afterwards, I am just looking for functionality as of right now.
This app also won't be accessible by those who aren't given direct permission through IP whitelisting and login protection.

@Jakkber, you are of course free to do as you want, however "I will be fixing things afterwards" too often never happens. This is one of those show-stoppers that I'd really recommend learning today, and not fixing tomorrow. Check out the links that aynber posted, they really aren't that complicated and honestly, your code will even read better because you aren't concatenating or escaping or anything like that. Also, "This app also won't be accessible" is also known as "famous last words".

@ChrisHaas haha fair enough! I'll get to it :)

You're not setting the $id in your actual else branch for the UPDATE... statement. Try it like this:
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database= "replog_test";

//create connection
$connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

$id = "";
$service_dept="";
$po="";
$customer="";
$pcs="";
$equipment="";
$date_rec="";
$problem="";
$warr="";
$date_ship="";

$errorMessage = "";
$successMessage = "";

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
    //GET method: Show the data of the client

    if (!isset($_GET["id"])) {
        header("location: /novasvm/index.php");
        exit;
    }

    $id = $_GET["id"];

    // read the row of the selected client from the database table
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM replog WHERE id=$id";
    $result = $connection->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    if (!$row) {
        header("location: /novasvm/index.php");
        exit;
    }

    $service_dept = $row["service_dept"];
    $po = $row["po"];
    $customer = $row["customer"];
    $pcs = $row["pcs"];
    $equipment = $row["equipment"];
    $date_rec = $row["date_rec"];
    $problem = $row["problem"];
    $warr = $row["warr"];
    $date_ship = $row["date_ship"];
}
else {
    // POST method: Update the data of the client
    $service_dept = $_POST["service_dept"];
    $po = $_POST["po"];
    $customer = $_POST["customer"];
    $pcs = $_POST["pcs"];
    $equipment = $_POST["equipment"];
    $date_rec = $_POST["date_rec"];
    $problem = $_POST["problem"];
    $warr = $_POST["warr"];
    $date_ship = $_POST["date_ship"];
    $id = $_POST["id"];   // <----------

    do {
        if ( empty($service_dept) || empty($po) || empty($customer) || empty($pcs) || empty($equipment) || empty($date_rec) || empty($problem) || empty($warr)) {
            $errorMessage = "All fields except DATE SHIPPED are required";
            break;
        }

        $sql = "UPDATE replog " . 
                "SET service_dept = '$service_dept', po = '$po', customer = '$customer', pcs = '$pcs', equipment = '$equipment', date_rec = '$date_rec', problem = '$problem', warr = '$warr', date_ship = '$date_ship' " . 
                "WHERE id = '$id'";

        $result = $connection->query($sql);
        
        if (!$result) {
            $errorMessage = "Invalid Query: " . $connection->error;
            break;
        }

        $successMessage = "Client Updated Correctly";
        header("location: /novasvm/general/replog.php");
        exit;

    } while(false);
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../reset.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Repair Log</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h2>New Data</h2>

        <?php  
        if ( !empty($errorMessage)) {
            echo "
            <div>
                <strong>$errorMessage</strong>
            </div>
            ";
        }          
        ?>

        <form method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
            <div>
                <label>Service Department</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="service_dept" value="<?php echo $service_dept; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>PO Number</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="po" value="<?php echo $po; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Customer</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="customer" value="<?php echo $customer; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Pieces</label>
                <div>
                    <select name="pcs" id="">
                        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Equipment</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="equipment" value="<?php echo $equipment; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Date Received</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="date" name="date_rec" value="<?php echo $date_rec; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Problem / Serial No.</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="problem" value="<?php echo $problem; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Warranty</label>
                <div>
                    <select name="warr" id="">
                        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                        <option value="no">No</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Date Shipped</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="date" name="date_ship" value="<?php echo $date_ship; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php
            if (!empty($successMessage)) {
                echo "
                <div>
                    <strong>$successMessage</strong>
                </div>
                ";
            }
            ?>

            <div>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="/novasvm/general/replog.php" role="button">Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>


Thank you, thank you, thank you!
I was on the brink of restarting. As I mentioned above I am very novice at this and am doing this as sort of a side project to hopefully help my company.

Such a silly error too! I understand it will be helpful to learn PHP and SQL fundamentals but for now I have to do it this way. My knowledge in other languages comes as a great benefit but it has been a huge challenge so far.
